# Query Optimization for less time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle10g, query-optimization

I have table emp, having 2 million records.
'Status' column has three values, 'Permanent','Contract','Intern'.
It is taking long time to execute. Is there any way to optimize this query so that it will take lesser time.
Below is the query:

```
SELECT dtls_info, 
       status,max(emp_id) -- COUNT(DISTINCT emp_id) 
FROM (
  SELECT status, dtls_info, emp_id 
  FROM (
    SELECT status, dtls_info, emp_id, modif_date, MAX(emp_id) OVER() AS max_emp_id 
    FROM emp
  ) 
  WHERE emp_id >= max_emp_id - 200000 
    and modif_date > sysdate - 1 / 24
)
where emp_id >= (select min(emp_id) from emp) 
GROUP BY status, dtls_info;
```

Comment: Which dbms? Show us table and index definitions. Any explain output?

Comment: Currently using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the various `min(emp_)id)` and `max(emp_id)` subqueries? They look like good candidates for causing poor performance but we can't suggest more efficient alternatives without understanding the business rules in play/

Comment: `emp_id >= (select min(emp_id) from emp)` isn't this always true? (I'm hoping no nulls in such a column.)

Comment: @Mat . . . It doesn't matter if there are `NULL`s because of the subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I think Mat's point is that a column called `emp_id` on a table called `emp` ought to be not null, which would make the subquery unnecessary.

Comment: @APC . . . I understand that.  But in the context of the query, the `NULL` check is happening even before that, so the reference to that line of code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest query which might would seem to be this:

```
SELECT dtls_info, 
       status,
       COUNT(DISTINCT emp_id) -- max(emp_id) 
FROM emp
WHERE modif_date > sysdate - 1 / 24
and emp_id is not null  
GROUP BY status, dtls_info;
```

This should perform reasonably well if there is a index on `modif_date` because you might get a index range scan operation. Even if it isn't indexed, removing the needless subquery on the same table will reduce the total elapsed time (because the query is doing less work).

It is concerning that you seem to need a test on the population of what seems like it ought to be a primary key column. If you genuinely have nulls in `emp_id` that may be a bug in the application you need to address.

I have ignored the test on `max_emp_id` as that seems like something that was added in an attempt to speed things up, rather than a valid business rule.

Comment: . . Although your query is more reasonable, it doesn't do exactly what the OP's query does.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Your query looks like:

```
SELECT dtls_info, 
       status,max(emp_id) -- COUNT(DISTINCT emp_id) 
FROM (SELECT status, dtls_info, emp_id 
      FROM (SELECT e.*, MAX(emp_id) OVER () AS max_emp_id 
            FROM emp e
           ) e
      WHERE emp_id >= max_emp_id - 200000 AND
            modif_date > sysdate - 1 / 24
     ) e
WHERE emp_id >= (select min(emp_id) from emp) 
GROUP BY status, dtls_info;
```

The outer `where` is immaterial (unless `emp_id` can be `NULL`.  This simplifies the query to:

```
SELECT dtls_info, status, max(emp_id) -- COUNT(DISTINCT emp_id) 
FROM (SELECT e.*, MAX(e.emp_id) OVER () AS max_emp_id 
      FROM emp e
     ) e
WHERE emp_id >= max_emp_id - 200000 AND
      modif_date > sysdate - 1 / 24
GROUP BY status, dtls_info;
```

The condition on `max_emp_id` is very curious.  But for this version, start with an index on `emp(emp_id, modif_date)`.  I tend to agree with APC that the conditions on `emp_id` are probably not necessary and that solution is probably what you really need.